# Add column from one .csv to another .csv file

Tags: bash, csv, join

file1.csv

```
A,,C,D
A,,C,D
A,,C,D
A,,C,D
```

file2.csv

```
A,B
A,B
A,B
A,B
```

desired Output.csv

```
A,B,C,D
A,B,C,D
A,B,C,D
A,B,C,D
```

I've tried using "join" and "paste" to no avail. Is there a bash command to do this? Column "A" is the same in both `.csv` files.

Comment: So you are asking to copy column B to File 1? Or columns C and D to file2?

Comment: Either way would be fine as long as the output matches "desiredOutput.csv"

Comment: I have added a new answer which, I think, is easier than all the other answers (my first answer included). You might want to consider accepting that so that for future reference the information is easily found.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### With only `awk` command:

```
awk -F, '{getline f1 <"file2" ;print f1,$3,$4}' OFS=, file1
```

Get a line from file1 and store it into local variable `f1`, then print the line that stored in `f1` and finally print the third(`$3`) and forth(`$3`) fields from file1 which delimited with comma `,` altogether, and change the OFS(output field separator [space by default]) to comma(`,`).

---

#### The short command would be like this:

```
paste -d, file2 <(cut -d, -f3- file1)
```

```
 A,B,C,D  
 A,B,C,D  
 A,B,C,D  
 A,B,C,D
```

paste the file2, then cut and paste the third column to the next(`-f3-`) from file1.

---

#### With `awk` and `paste` (option A)

Below command also copies the last two columns (`C,D`) from file1 at the end of each line in file2:

```
paste -d',' file2  <(awk -F',' '{print $(NF-1)","$NF}' file1)
```

Above command [paste](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/paste.1posix.html) the file2 content then print a comma delimiter(`-d','`) then paste the two last field(`NF` is the index of last field and `$NF` is the string which its index is `NF`. So `$(NF-1)` is the second field before last field ) from file1 when those index redefines or splits with comma spectator(`-F','`).

#### With `awk` and `paste` (option B)

This command also is the same as above(`$3` and `$4` points to third and forth field of each line from file1 ):

```
paste -d',' file2  <(awk -F',' '{print $3","$4}' file1)
```

#### Or another solution with `cut` command:

```
paste -d, <(cut -d, -f1 file1) <(cut -d, -f2 file2) <(cut -d, -f3- file1)
```

[cut](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/cut.1posix.html) command in above command first cut the first field(`-f1` which indexed with comma delimiter(`-d.`)) from file1(`cut -d, -f1 file1`), then cut and paste the second field of file2(`cut -d, -f2 file2`) and finally cut and paste the third column(`-f3`) to the nexts(`-`) from file1(`cut -d, -f3- file1`) again.

#### This command also returns the same result:

```
paste -d, <(awk -F',' '{print $1}' file1) <(awk -F',' '{print $2}' file2) <(awk -F',' '{print $3","$4}' file1)
```

paste the second field from file1(`awk -F',' '{print $1}' file1`) then print a comma(`-d,`), then paste the second column from file2(`awk -F',' '{print $2}' file2`), finally paste the second and last column of file1(`awk -F',' '{print $3","$4}' file1`) again.

Comment: @kasi you could do this through awk itself. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14984673/3297613

Answer (score 9):

## Here's a beauty (I think):

```
join -t, <(csvcut -c 1,3,4 file1.csv) <(csvcut -c 1,2 file2.csv)
```

---

## Broken down in steps:

Step 1. Install csvkit:

```
sudo pip install csvkit
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-pip python-setuptools build-essential
```

Step 2. Use the join command with a comma as separator

```
join -t,
```

Step 3. Feed it the actual columns you want to. Note how you feed it the first column twice, because that is the one the join is actually performed on (default behavior of `join`).

```
join -t, <(csvcut --columns 1,3,4 file1.csv) <(csvcut --columns 1,2 file2.csv)
```

or in shorthand:

```
join -t, <(csvcut -c 1,3,4 file1.csv) <(csvcut -c 1,2 file2.csv)
```

You can redirect that standard output to a file (desiredOutput) if wanted.

## Advantages

This method has several advantages over the others proposed.

First and foremost: it performs a real join. That means that it can be used for more complex data as well. It is very easy to do a join on another field, for instance. It does not simply look at the position of the field, but it really takes the column into consideration. It actually works with the format of the data (csv) and does not treat it like text.

Second, it uses the very powerful csv toolkit which also allows you to a) display statistics with one command (`csvstats)`, b) check whether the data is clean (`csvclean`), but also to transform it into json, into sql, or even load it into python! This toolkit is heavily used in data science for data preparation.

Comment: If you are installing on Ubuntu you may need to install the Python development headers prior to installing csvkit: `sudo apt-get install python-dev python-pip python-setuptools build-essential` -- [link](https://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.0/)

Comment: Awesome answer as well, I'm working on a company server so installing stuff takes about a week of paper work. Works on my machine though!

Comment: +1 for showing me another tool for CSV data. Separate question, but do you know of a standalone report writer for CSV data files?

Comment: @Joe can you be a more specific about what you mean when you speak about a 'report writer'? I am not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: I posted a separate question at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170199/is-there-a-standalone-tool-which-will-write-reports-from-csv-data-files/170201#170201

Comment: @Joe with a report do you mean the averages, the maximum values, and that sort of stuff? If so, I can help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure what I want. I have to play with the actual data, but it would be things like subtotals per week of credits and debits. I also had some call center utilization data where I wanted to sum and average calls per minute. Nothing Fancy. I barely got a C in statistics for social sciences and I've forgotten most of that. I also would like to select columns without pre-filtering it in awk, etc.. I can code all of it in a programming language like awk, but for such a common task, there should be something that already knows how to do it.

Comment: @Joe look into csvkit. It has a tool called csvstat which gives you some statistics. It also has a few nice tools to select columns etc. All the things you are saying you can do with csvkit *if* you read the manual.

Answer (score 8):

Here is another beautiful one. I think it is the easiest of all suggestions, thus far.

```
csvtool pastecol 2 2 file1.csv file2.csv
```

If you have not installed csvtool already in the past, you have to `sudo apt-get install csvtool`.

From the docs:

> ```
> pastecol <column-spec1> <column-spec2> input.csv update.csv
> ```
>
> Replace the content of the columns referenced by  in the
>   file input.csv with the one of the corresponding column specified by
>    in update.csv.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
>   csvtool pastecol 2-3 1- input.csv update.csv.csv > output.csv
> ```

Note how in our case we are replacing the second columns of the files.

## Examples

file1.csv

```
A,,C,D
A,,C,D
A,,C,D
A,,C,D
```

file2.csv

```
A,B
A,B
A,B
A,B
```

Combining the two files:

```
csvtool pastecol 2 2 file1.csv file2.csv
A,B,C,D
A,B,C,D
A,B,C,D
A,B,C,D
```

What you essentially do is paste the column two of `file2.csv` as column 2 in `file1.csv`.

Note that this also works on the same document. If you want to swap two columns, you can do so by using the same file as input.csv and update.vsc.

```
csvtool pastecol 2 1 file2.csv file2.csv 
A,A
A,A
A,A 
A,A
```

Comment: No doubt the most elegant.

Answer (score 2):

To move a chosen number of columns from one file to another:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

cols = 1; file_1 = "/path/to/file_1"; file_2 = "/path/to/file_2"

def readfile(file):
      with open(file) as src:
          return [item.strip().split(",") for item in src.readlines()]

file_1 = readfile(file_1); file_2 = readfile(file_2)

for i in range(len(file_1)):
    print((",").join(file_1[i]+file_2[i][-cols:]))
```

from two files:

file_1

```
A,B
A,B
A,B
A,B
```

file_2

```
K,L,M
K,L,M
K,L,M
K,L,M
```

When you set `cols = 1`:

```
A,B,M
A,B,M
A,B,M
A,B,M
```

But When you set `cols = 2`:

```
A,B,L,M
A,B,L,M
A,B,L,M
A,B,L,M
```

`cols = 3`:

```
A,B,K,L,M
A,B,K,L,M
A,B,K,L,M
A,B,K,L,M
```

#### How to use

Copy it into an empty file, set the path to `file1`, `file2` and the number of columns to move, save it as `move.py` and run it by:

```
python3 /path/to/move.py
```

It is also possible to add one or more columns from the middle of the source file's colums this way.

Comment: Would have loved to see you use `import csv` though.

Comment: @don.joey Thanks for the suggestion, will definitely look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Another method in python through csv module.

`script.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import csv
import sys
file1 = sys.argv[1]
file2 = sys.argv[2]
with open(file2, 'r') as r:
    with open(file1, 'r') as f:
        csv_f = csv.reader(f)
        csv_r = csv.reader(r)
        bar = [linex for linex in csv_r]
        foo = [liney[2:] for liney in csv_f]
        zipped = zip(bar,foo)
        result = [x+y for (x,y) in list(zipped)]
        for i in result:
            print(','.join(i))
```

To run the above script,

```
python3 script.py file1 file2
```

Output:

```
A,B,C,D
A,B,C,D
A,B,C,D
A,B,C,D
```